# How to parse email body in Python?

Tags: python, email

How to parse only text data from an email?

There are multiple types of emails from inbox.

- Only text
- Blank email
- Text with html
- html with attachment
- text with attachment

How to identify the email type and then extract emails with only text.

I have created a function to loop through emails, but I'm stuck at extracting the body for few emails. 
I'm getting the below error on this line :

```
 email.message_from_string(response_part[1].decode('utf-8'))
```

'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 : invalid start byte

**Function to loop through emails**

```
    def read_email:
        try:
            mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(SMTP_SERVER)
            mail.login(FROM_EMAIL,FROM_PWD)
            mail.select('inbox')

            type, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
            mail_ids = data[0]

            id_list = mail_ids.split()

            for i in reversed(id_list):
                typ, data = mail.fetch(i, '(RFC822)')

                for response_part in data:
                     if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
                        msg = email.message_from_string(response_part[1].decode('utf-8'))
                        email_subject = msg['subject']
                        email_from = msg['from']
                        email_to = msg['to']
                        emailid  = msg['message-id']

        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
```

Comment: Your question is probably too broad. The immediate problem is that your byte stream *obviously* isn't UTF-8 so there is no reason for you to attempt to decode it, or for the attempt to succeed. More broadly, there are many ways in MIME to serialize a particular message, and you need to understand these variations and their significance; but a Stack Overflow question is probably too narrow in scope for that discussion.

Comment: you can try this if you didnt see examples of sending mails and parsing them .https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html